# Can I create a new Target in Xcode using Apple Script without using any third party tools or frameworks

Tags: xcode, applescript

I would like to do following tasks using Apple Script

1. Create new target
2. Change bundle name and version number
3. Add existing files to the newly created target

is it possible using Apple Script?

thanks in Advance